# filter Document library based on metadata

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, 2016, filter, filtermulivalue

Using SP-2016
I have a document library with 10K+ document and 12 metadata fields which is lookup columns from different different lists.

to search specific genre of records,  I want to filters that will filter the documents.  Filter data should come from the metadata columns.

I don't want to use filter-webpart.

Comment: If Microsoft did not remove the "Metadata navigation settings" from lists in SharePoint 2016, they should work fine. Take a look at the list settings.

Comment: these are Lookup columns ...

Answer (score 0):

I agree use "Metadata navigation settings" in site settings to create and organize the meta data and then go to settings and for that specific list/library presss "allow tree view" and then you can view all the documents based on the specific meta data tags

Comment: Again my concern is, will SharePoint allow Lookup columns to be in "Metadata Navigation" !!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use library built-in search "Find a File" to filter documents:
[image]